# Парсинг HTML разметки в Python

Tags: python, парсер

Есть сайт: https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/1/1. На нём нужно спарсить все ники с таблицы. К сожалению, у меня нет идей как это реализовать.

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/1/1'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

rows = [ row.find_all('td')[1].text for row in soup.find_all('tr') ]
print(rows[1::])  # ['Tobio_Edison', 'Alfonso_Wayne', ...]
```